# find all DUPLICATE TOPICS NAME mysql

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

I am running a query like this:

```
SELECT id, title, COUNT( * ) c FROM news GROUP BY title HAVING c >1 LIMIT 22
```

but it's take long time to respond how to Optimizing it ?

Comment: run a explain and see what's the query plan

Comment: show the output of `show create table news` and read this I just wrote up http://stackoverflow.com/a/39551434

Comment: Make sure you have an index on `title`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to Optimize it must title have index

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name);
```

that will help sql to remember titles and search faster