# SQL request with mysql strict mode

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1055

I have an error with a sql request with mysql 7.0
Do you have an idea on this request to change?

> [18-Sep-2016 13:08:17 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.p.products_model' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in /home/www/clicshopping_test_ui/boutique/includes/ClicShopping/OM/DbStatement.php on line 97

My request about this error

```
$QuppliersProducts1 = $OSCOM_Db->prepare('
        select  p.products_model,s.suppliers_id, 
                sum(op.products_quantity) as sum_qty,    
                s.suppliers_name,op.products_name, 
                opa.products_options, opa.products_options_values   
        from :table_orders_products  op
            left join :table_products p ON op.products_id = p.products_id
            left join :table_suppliers s on p.suppliers_id = s.suppliers_id
            left join :table_orders  o ON op.orders_id = o.orders_id
            left join :table_orders_products_attributes opa ON op.orders_products_id = opa.orders_products_id
        where o.date_purchased between :date_purchased_start  
            and :date_purchased_end
            and s.suppliers_id = :suppliers_id
            and o.orders_status = :orders_status 
            and s.suppliers_id = :suppliers_id
        group by op.products_name, opa.products_options, 
                  opa.products_options_values
        order by p.products_model, op.products_name');

  $QuppliersProducts1->bindInt(':date_purchased_start', (int)$_GET['bDS'] );
  $QuppliersProducts1->bindInt(':date_purchased_end', (int)$_GET['bED'] );
  $QuppliersProducts1->bindInt(':suppliers_id', (int)$_GET['bID'] );
  $QuppliersProducts1->bindInt(':orders_status', (int)$_GET['bOS'] );

  $QuppliersProducts1->execute();
```

Comment: You can't bind tables/columns.

Comment: in addition to the above, see my recent answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39551434

Comment: You aren't grouping by `p.products_model` ,`s.suppliers_id`, or `s.suppliers_name`. That is what is giving the error on `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`