# MySQL grouping and summing

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a query that returns a table that looks something like this:

```
+------+----------+-------+------+----+
| pID  | name     | month | q    | s  |
+------+----------+-------+------+----+
| 1468 | bob      |     2 |    1 | 14 |
| 1469 | bob      |     2 |    1 |  2 |
| 1470 | bob      |     2 |    1 |  9 |
| 1468 | bob      |     3 |    1 |  7 |
| 1469 | bob      |     3 |    1 |  8 |
| 1470 | bob      |     3 |    1 | 11 |
+------+----------+-------+------+----+
```

and I would like the output to be

```
+----------+-------+------+-----+
| name     | month | q    | sub |
+----------+-------+------+-----+
| bob      |     2 |    1 |  25 |
| bob      |     3 |    1 |  26 |
+----------+-------+------+-----+
```

Essentially, I want the first two columns of my output to be `name`, `month` and `q`  grouped by `name` and `month` (they will always have the same data per line in this grouping) and I want the last column to be the SUM of `s` grouped by `name` only.

Thanks.

Comment: `only_full_group_by` ... you better  hope columns 2 and 3 are what you want or roll the dice. You results fall in lines with these two question: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39563792) and [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39551434) . Your col1 and col4 will be just fine. The middle two will haphazardly arrive, perhaps, not in the random fashion that you wish. Such as a distinct row fed from MRU cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
SELECT name, month, q, SUM(sub)
FROM table
GROUP BY name, month, q
```

Comment: This solution seems to give me what I want. I will have to check further to be sure.